# What popular applications that use ClickOnce as a depoyment solution?

Tags: windows, installation, deployment

What are some examples of popular or mainstream applications that use [ClickOnce](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ClickOnce) as their deployment solution? (Go ahead and use your own definition of popular.)

[MetroTwit](http://www.metrotwit.com/), a fairly popular Twitter client, comes to mind, but I'm looking for some more examples.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" -> every answer is equally valid, there is no actual problem to be solved, ...

Comment: @slhck This is not a subjective or open-ended question, an application is either using ClickOnce or it isn't. The problem to be solved is that I'm looking for applications that people might recognize so I can demonstrate the technology.

Comment: `avoid asking questions where … (1) every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”  (2) your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”` - [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Microsoft Visual Basic Express Editions use Clickonce for installation (or at least deployment/download, the installers themselves are still hideously complicated). They use something called the Microsoft Web Platform Installer which some sites indicate is a part of the ClickOnce family.

See here for a link to Microsoft's Web App Gallery which is based on the WebPI: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/

Comment: To the editor: I post "undressed" links as a security habit, so people can see where they are being taken without having to search for the browser's status bar. Your other edits were unsubstantive.